# When to dynamically compute data vs. when to use variables and update on demand?

Tags: design-patterns

Two scenarios:

1. Function is called and data is computed and returned.
2. Data is saved in variable, updated when required, data is retrieved from variable.

So I was wondering in what kind of scenarios one would be beneficial over the other?

Comment: For starters, how long does it take to compute the data? How often is that done, where is it used and by how many processes? Is there simultaneous access? Your second point brings us to databases and database theory.

Comment: [Space–time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).